# Word document export from ECLIPSE IDE

Tags: eclipse, ruta, xmi

I need to export a Word document -or in any other readable form, not an xml file for example- from Eclipse IDE showing the results of the annotations. 
The files i am currently working on have an .xmi extension.
Have you got any idea how to do this?

Comment: The UIMA Ruta supports .xmi (i.e. .xml) and some other non-textual formats as output only. What you could do though, is to write a Java Analysis Engine that reads the Ruta .xmi output and writes the annotations in any desired textual format. The Java Analysis Engine can be called within Ruta as uimaFIT engine (see the documentation [link](https://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html)) .